# FIX API quickfix multithreading

Tags: api, quickfix, quickfixj

What is the proper way of connecting to mulitple servers/acceptors using quickfix?

1. Create a thread for each session under the fix application
2. Create a seperate application for each session, create multiple initiators, start each initiator in a seperate thread

And another related issue -
How does MultiThreadedInitiator class fits in...?

Answer (score 1):

Quickfix already allows multiple sessions. They just have to be defined in your configuration file. From then on you can track messages using SessionID.

I think MultiThreadedInitiator ensures each session is created in a different thread.